# C++ - SFML - OpenGL - GLSL - smooth waving texture

Tags: c++, glsl, sfml

I have this shaders:

Fragment:

```
uniform float time;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    float t = time;
    vec2 aux = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;

    // This would also make waving/deform the texture
    //aux.x = aux.x + (sin(aux.y * time *.5) * 0.05);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, aux);
}
```

Vertex:

```
uniform float time;

void main()
{
    vec4 vertex = gl_Vertex;
    vertex.x = vertex.x + sin(time - vertex.y * 20) / 10;
    vertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix * vertex;

    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * vec4(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z, vertex.w);
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

I am used that shader on low resolution textures(I have for example a grass tile texture of 8x8 pixels) to create a 2D waving grass effect.
The problem is, that the shader effect is now very choppy because the texture resolution.
Now I am wonder me, is it not possible to let the shader make more steps and make that "animation" smoother ?

Comment: use linear interpolation? also scale the time by something other than .5

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. I also simply set the antialiasing level much higher.